# Including headers in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, include

In C++, does one need to copy any needed header files into the directory of the main C++ file?

Ex. I have OpenCV installed globally, and the Python bindings are working well. However, if I write:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

I receive a "not found" error. Do I need to copy these from their global install location to the project dir? I'm certain there must be a well-established set of practices for this, so I don't want to poke around in the dark on my own.

Comment: Usually you tell the compiler where to look for include files. And that depends on the compiler and/or IDE.

Comment: @juanchopanza ... and where the actual installation of a lib is placed on the development machine.

Comment: You should never have to copy the headers or even the libraries into your project. You may however have to adjust an environment variable, compiler setting in a project file or some setting in an IDE that tells the compiler where to look.

Comment: Since you mentioned OpenCV. I recommend you use CMake to generate your project files for your compiler. CMake setup the paths correctly for you.

Comment: @drescherjm Just spent some time playing with CMake, what a great cool! You've just greatly eased by wading into C from the austere high level world of Python, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which operating system and build tool chain you are using, but as an example using linux, gcc and cmake, this article shows how to build with opencv.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

As you can see with the `find_package` directive, cmake is searching for the opencv include files.

Obviously, you can specify include path directly with `g++ -I`, but having cmake find it for you has the advantage that it will have a better chance of being found if you compile on a different system. It will also give you an error if it can't find the files.

Lastly, you should ensure that you have the "dev" files, as opposed to just the library. The dev files will have headers to include. While, the library will only have shared objects (`*.so`) and archives (`*.a`) that can be used for static or runtime linking.

Comment: Tutorial was helpful, all functioning as desired now. Also appreciate the suggestion using flags.

Comment: Sounds good. I also think Tomás Badan's suggestion is good. You may want to try that too. I've upvoted his as well.

Answer (score 3):

If it is installed globally, you need to inform the compiler to look globally, i.e.,

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```